# Why breeze sends to server originalvaluesMap for unmapped property?

Tags: breeze

I'm using breeze 1.4.11 with Web Api and EFContextProvider

on client after metadata fetched I extend entity type:

```
var addressStringProperty = new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "addressString",
    isUnmapped: true
})
metadataStore.getEntityType('Account').addProperty(addressStringProperty);
```

this property is computed and used only on client

after `entitymanager.saveChanges([accountEntity])` I see on server side in `contextprovider.BeforeSaveEntity` that `entityInfo.OriginalvaluesMap` contains Key "AddressString" with Value == null.

same thing with extending entity like:

```
var accountCtor = function() {
  this.addressString = ko.observable()
};
metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Account', accountCtor);
```

How to omit this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question and probably an oversight. I'll add it as a new bug, but... just out of curiousity, why is this problematic for you?

Comment: I check on server what properties were changed on client. Some users are limited in editing entities. In this case user can edit only one particular property but client sent two in originalValuesMap.

Comment: OriginalValuesMap does not contain keys for those properties that were added in entity initializer, so problem can be solved actually.